# How to create a .net core generic host to run other .net projects?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to create a .net core generic host that accepts a generic `Startup.cs` type so that I can run different .net core projects from within an integration test.

This is what I have as my wrapper...

```cs
public class ProviderHost<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    public void StartProvider()
    {
        var apiUnderTestBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseStartup<TStartup>();
                builder.UseEnvironment("Development");
                builder.UseUrls($"http://0.0.0.0:5000");
            }).Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

The code is then simply called like this from within a unit test in a separate unit test project

```cs
var providerHost = new ProviderHost<Startup>();

providerHost.StartProvider();
```

The `Startup` type here is another .net core webapi project reference.

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work as posting to a known endpoint at `http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/events` just keeps spinning in Postman or doesn't return via curl. This same request works if I run the project the `Startup` belongs to directly.

I am getting the following logging which suggests the web host is starting correctly

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5000
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: C:\OconnorEvents\OconnorEvents.EventCatalog.Tests\bin\Debug\net5.0
```

If I also put some debug statements in the `Startup.cs` that is referenced I can see that it flows through both `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` without any issues.

If I do a `netstat -a -b` I can see that port `5000` is only being used when the unit test is running.

Where am I going wrong here?

I'm aware that I could just start the project with a `dotnet run` or run it in docker and point tests at it. You'll have to trust my reasons for wanting to do it this way :)

Comment: `when the unit test is running.  that is the right thing to do. Only spin up resources and shut them down  when you're finish. Why you need to add more complex things ?

Comment: I require more granular control over the running application, including a different middleware pipeline

Comment: Shouldn't the address be `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`? It may be an issue if you have two networks interfaces.

Comment: @RafaelBiz Doesn't make a difference I'm afraid